# com.sun.proxy.$Proxy error on creating pointcut on jdbcTemplate

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, proxy, aspectj, spring-aop

I try to make a pointcut, to log the SQL queries

```
  @Before("execution(* org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.*(String, ..))")
public void logSQLQueries() {
        System.out.println("@@");
    }
```

I am trying to implement the code as here; 
http://www.gotoquiz.com/web-coding/programming/java-programming/log-sql-statements-with-parameter-values-filled-in-spring-jdbc/

but I get

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate field com.xyz.abc.dao.ABCDaoImpl.jdbcTemplate to com.sun.proxy.$Proxy53
```

I have created the jdbcTemplate bean in my *-servlet.xml and have autowired this in all my DAO's. Works perfectly fine but adding the pointcut gives the exception. Any ideas ??

Comment: Program to interfaces instead of concrete classes. Spring uses proxies to apply AOP. Instead of `JdbcTemplate` use `JdbcOperations` the latter is the interface (which you probably also want to use in yourp ointcut). Or switch from interface based proxies to classbased proxies, or don't use proxies but use loadtime weaving to apply aspects.

Comment: The example you are pointing to even does what @M.Deinum just told you, you modified it! BTW, Spring AOP also works with classes instead of the preferable interfaces, but then you need CGLIB on your classpath.

Comment: I did first try with the interface, but when it didn't work, I was trying something different. I do not understand the concept of proxies here. can you please provide a reference where I can understand the concept. Also, how do I switch to class based proxy, or use load time weaving. Thanks for replying, please do put an answer so that I can mark it.

Comment: @kriegaex I already have cglib in my classpath, can you please explain how it is supposed to help here. Thanks

Comment: Please post a full callstack and switch back to the interface.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Spring, by default, uses JDK Dynamic proxies to apply AOP. (For more information on proxies see [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-understanding-aop-proxies)).

What happens isthat a dynamic class is created (`com.sun.proxy.$Proxy53`) which implements all the interfaces that the target class implements. For a `JdbcTemplate` that is `JdbcOperations` and `InitializingBean`. So the dynamic class is a `JdbcOperations` but not a `JdbcTemplate` and hence the injection fails.

You have a couple of solutions

1. Use the interface `JdbcOperations` instead of the class `JdbcTemplate` to program against
2. Use class based proxies
3. Use loadtime weaving

Now option 1 and 2 are the easiest whereas option 3 is the most powerful and complex to get started (see the links below).

For 1 in your class change

```
@Autowired
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
```

To

```
@Autowired
private JdbcOperations jdbcTemplate;
```

If you are extending `JdbcDaoSupport` you might be in a pickle and then it won't work.

Option 2, assuming you have `<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />` set the `proxy-target-class` attribute to `true`. This will require cglib and will create class based proxies instead of interface based proxies.

For option 3 I refer to [the reference guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-aj-ltw) as that involves (probably) a java-agent and might be a little more complicated to get working.

Links

1. [Understanding AOP proxies](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-understanding-aop-proxies)
2. [Load-time weaving with AspectJ](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-aj-ltw)

Comment: Tried first two solutions, they do not work. At least in Spring 4.2.x

Comment: Then you have a different problem (basically the first one should always work, if that doesn't;t work you have some how managed to enable to (probably) create a proxy of a proxy).